# np.std change ddof within groupby

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pandas-groupby

I was running a manual (I wrote a function) std dev versus numpy's built in.

There was a slight difference in the returned values.

I looked it up and numpy uses ddof=0 by default.

I am trying to figure out how to pass that within a groupby and I am failing.

My groupby is simply this:  grouped = houses.groupby('Yr Sold').agg({'SalePrice': np.std})

If I use: np.std(ddof=1) it errors out saying I am missing the required positional argument 'a'.

I looked that up and I see what it is, but it seems to me that 'a' is my 'SalePrice' column.

I have tried a few different ways but every single thing I try results in a syntax error.

Using the groupby syntax above, how do I pass the ddof=1 parameter to adjust numpy's default behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to solve my problem, just not by directly using the syntax above.

```
std_dev_dict = {}
for id, group in houses.groupby('Yr Sold'):
    std_dev_dict[id] = np.std(group['SalePrice'], ddof=1)
print(std_dev_dict)
```